# I can run compiled .go file without chmod

Tags: linux, script, chmod

I am learning to program in google's Go language, I have a script:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

So I compiled it with:

```
go build /home/user/HelloWorld.go
```

I noticed that I could run the compiled result without executing:

```
chmod +x /home/user/HelloWorld
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because the `go` compiler does the +x for you?

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the build command is invoking several pieces of the go tool chain with the implicit aim of producing an *executable*. You could ask go to only compile, say, or link, taking each tool in turn, and it would only be the last step in the build toolchain that actually sets the executable bit.

This is not specifically a go thing. It's what compiler tool chains do. You should bear in mind that a shell script is not a compiled executable: that's why you need to set the executable bit so that when the kernel reads the first line it knows to invoke the shell and pass the script body to it.